# Opencv in c++ outputting image to web

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I need some advice please. I have a Lidar on a linux server creating a image every few miliseconds but when I look at it in the web browser and refresh, it sometimes show half the created image. I get that this  is because the program is writing the image to the web servers directory while the image is reloading.(Is there a better way)

I want to use opencv and c++ as I want to be able to do differences in the images and show
movement activity. The Lidar libs are also written in c++.

My Questions:
Can I make opencv turn this image into a rtsp / http feed from one updating image.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Write to a temp file and swap it with the actively retrieved image on completion?

Comment: So you saying write it to tmp and then on completion move it to the web server dir... Interesting

Comment: Yep, just like how GPU prevent tearing, should be swift since the filesystem only need to update their name

Comment: Do i move it in the c++ program or use system commands... Whats more efficient

Comment: Should be very similar, I'd prefer std::filesystem::rename to improve portability. Remember, on renaming its only their name (including path) that's being updated, so a very small operation. *Don't* use copy command since it require actually duplicating the file content

Comment: You sir are a GOD!